# How can I make my preferred keyboard mapping consistent throughout my Linux installation? (CentOS 8)

Tags: centos, gnome, keyboard-layout

When I installed CentOS 8, I had the option to select a keyboard layout for use with the installation process and when using the operating system after installation. My choice was Norwegian Macintosh, no dead keys. (I have [this](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Apple_Keyboard_with_Numeric_Keyboard_9612.jpg) keyboard) I enabled disk encryption during install and typed in a password. Once I got into Gnome, I installed the kmod Nvidia Drivers, and this caused Wayland to be disabled ( I mention this in case it has some effect on keyboard layout). My password use some level 3 symbols.

Now I have inconsistencies in layout between the decryption screen (during boot), the session login screen for gnome, terminals and general UI.

Ive had a look at [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12510/relationship-of-keyboard-layout-and-xmodmap/12518#12518), but the answer there does not help me understand where/what config file I need to amend.

How can I make sure that all the above situations use the same keyboard layout, and not different ones?