# Are the keycodes of modifier characters independent of keyboard layout and keyboard model?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, keyboard-event

For example, is the keycode of left control always 37? Where can I find a list of such keycodes?

Comment: Yes, well mostly. There will be other keyboard types. But these are now rare.

Comment: Related question https://askubuntu.com/q/874934/21005

Answer (score 1):

No - it depends upon the keyboard configuration (ultimately upon hardware).  If you're using the same hardware all the time, this is not an issue.

xterm uses keycodes in the [**`modifyOtherKeys`**](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:modifyOtherKeys) feature.  Some of the background (and examples for several keyboard types) are given in the [*XTerm – “Other” Modified Keys*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/modified-keys.html) page.

The tables on that page are generated by [*modify-keys.pl*](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/xterm-snapshots/blob/master/vttests/modify-keys.pl), a script which imitates xterm's behavior for a given X keyboard configuration.  It gets some of the information from ["localectl status"](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/xterm-snapshots/blob/94c7ce6cab2371ba6eec668ab7c9c3dd28e076b5/vttests/modify-keys.pl#L1038), and some from [setkbmap](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/xterm-snapshots/blob/master/vttests/modify-keys.pl#L1122) (in more or less readable form).  Ultimately that comes from tables which are compiled from other sources, but those utilities were the easiest way to get usable information from the X keyboard configuration.

Checking my memory, I made a script to show the details of the variations in those tables:

```
#!/bin/sh
for kbd in apple altgr-intl pc105
do
for lang in us gb fr
do
setxkbmap -model $kbd -layout $lang -print | \
        xkbcomp - -C -o - >/tmp/$kbd-$lang.log 2>/dev/null
done
done
```

The X **keycode** happens to be the index into the `symCache` array defined in those source-files, e.g., around here:

```
#define NUM_SYMBOLS     358
static KeySym   symCache[NUM_SYMBOLS]= {
```

But the table-size changes with different configurations:

```
altgr-intl-fr.log:#define NUM_SYMBOLS   347
altgr-intl-gb.log:#define NUM_SYMBOLS   348
altgr-intl-us.log:#define NUM_SYMBOLS   254
apple-fr.log:#define NUM_SYMBOLS        358
apple-gb.log:#define NUM_SYMBOLS        359
apple-us.log:#define NUM_SYMBOLS        265
pc105-fr.log:#define NUM_SYMBOLS        375
pc105-gb.log:#define NUM_SYMBOLS        376
pc105-us.log:#define NUM_SYMBOLS        282
```

and the left/right control symbols appear at different offsets in some of the tables:

```
altgr-intl-fr.log:       XK_Control_L,      XK_Super_L,      XK_Shift_R,    XK_Control_R,
altgr-intl-gb.log:       XK_Control_L,      XK_Super_L,      XK_Shift_R,    XK_Control_R,
altgr-intl-us.log:        XK_Num_Lock,      XK_Shift_L,    XK_Control_L,      XK_Super_L,
apple-fr.log:       XK_Control_L,      XK_Super_L,      XK_Shift_R,    XK_Control_R,
apple-gb.log:       XK_Control_L,      XK_Super_L,      XK_Shift_R,    XK_Control_R,
apple-us.log:        XK_Num_Lock,      XK_Shift_L,    XK_Control_L,      XK_Super_L,
pc105-fr.log:       XK_Control_L,            XK_q,            XK_Q,           XK_at,
pc105-gb.log:       XK_Control_L,            XK_a,            XK_A,           XK_ae,
pc105-us.log:        XK_Num_Lock,      XK_Shift_L,    XK_Control_L,      XK_Super_L,
```

So I'd not expect those keycodes to **always** be the same values for all keyboard configurations.

The comment about `xev` mentions a way to see the keycodes for the current configuration.  On mine, the left control is **67** (not **37**):

```
KeyRelease event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
    root 0x111, subw 0xa00002, time 51155669, (23,30), root:(43,73),
    state 0x4, keycode 67 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
    root 0x111, subw 0xa00002, time 51156901, (23,30), root:(43,73),
    state 0x0, keycode 70 (keysym 0xffe4, Control_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Comment: I just need the codes for a script that is supposed to detect if a modifier key is pressed from `xinput`'s output. And it would be great if the script would work on other people's computers, too.

Comment: "xinput test" gives some numbers, but those aren't X ***keycodes***.  You might find [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12510/relationship-of-keyboard-layout-and-xmodmap?rq=1) helpful, though some of it is incorrect...

Comment: Are you sure? It gives the same number as `xev` gives for "keycode".

Comment: sorry - I was looking at the *keysyms* column of a table.  xev is (agreed) giving consistent results for *keycodes*